# Why some PNG can't use gl.REPEAT for gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S/T?

Tags: png, webgl, textures

```
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.REPEAT);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.REPEAT);
```

I have two png files, the first bigger one repeat success, and the second one failure, just show nothing in webgl canvas, just the same code as shown above. I made second picture by screen capture tool from the first one.
[the first one, original picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXkxr.png)
[the second one, screen capture from the first one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpdWv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using WebGL 1 then the reason is that the dimensions of the second image are not a power of two, the only texture wrap that works on npot(non-power of two) textures is `CLAMP`.

Comment: Thanks, I checked your answer, that's right.